# Set WordPress as SAML IDP with SimpleSaml.php

Tags: php, wordpress, single-sign-on, saml, simplesamlphp

I want to set up my WordPress website as a SAML IDP in order to connect to another website with WP credentials.
I know there is a log of plug-ins whose coming from mini orange but I want to set it up as my self.
So, I've installed SimpleSAML.php on my machine but I don't know what to chose as an auth source.
I tried via sql but I don't know how to create the SQL query as passwords are protected in the WP DB.
I was wondering if there is a way to call a custom WP API which check if credentials are good or not ...

I'm a bit lost on this so if anyone has ideas on it, I'll take it !

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/32018

Comment: Okay, I understand better how it works in PHP but now I'm wondering how I can implements this as a SimpleSaml.php Auth Source ?

Comment: You have a couple of options. I'm going to completely ignore the SimpleSAML portion because I'm hoping you've got that portion down. In your code, you can either boot a lite copy of WordPress and check the password, or you can copy that code, minus the filter stuff, and use it natively. The latter assumes you have no plugins in the auth path. Another option is to write your own [API endpoint](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/), but I'd be careful to guard that to your app only so that you don't leak.

Comment: Well, actually, I was already thinking about an API endpoint because I know how to create it. The fact is I don't know what put in the SimpleSAML auth source. Any idea ?

Comment: I had a similar situation about 5 or so years ago, WordPress site and I needed to do some SAML/IDP stuff. I spent a lot of time trying to setup and integrate SimpleSAML and in the end gave up. Luckily my use-case was relatively simple, and I was able to just treat the integration as a custom application with specific HTTP endpoints, and manually create and respond to HTTP requests. I used parts of [xmlseclibs](https://github.com/simplesamlphp/xmlsec), too. So unfortunately I'm not much help here.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed Wordpress uses a custom hashing algorithm so using SQLauth directly is not possible,

You could do two things:

1. Create the API endpoint in Wordpress that checks a username and password, and then create your own auth source module that checks this. This is not hard, there's some docs here and you can look at the exampleauth module to copy from. What you need to add are the API calls in the right places in your own module.
2. Do read directly from the database. You then need to modify/copy the sqlauth module so you encode the password with Wordpress'es hashing algorithm before it's checked.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use wordpress as an auth source in SimpleSAML, try https://github.com/OliverMaerz/WordpressAuth

I have it working since 3 years, together with SimpleSAML 1.19